# I can't see the color of flutter's borer's color Textfield()

Tags: flutter, colors, border

I can see the color change of `enabledBorder` and `focusedBorder` right away, but I can't see the color change of the border

whole codes

```
TextField(
  enabled: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "영화 제목을 검색해주세요.",
    helperText: 'helper',
    labelText: 'label',
    counterText: 'counter',
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red, // Default border color
      ),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.blue, // 테두리를 투명하게 만듭니다.
      ),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.green, // Border color when focused
      ),
    ),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I wonder why the color change of the border is invisible and how can I change it

I've changed the color of the appbar to be transparent, and I've disabled the border

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/border.html).

> Only the border's shape is used. If custom BorderSide values are
> desired for a given state, all four borders – errorBorder,
> focusedBorder, enabledBorder, disabledBorder – must be set.

If you are trying to set the color of the disabled textfield. Then you should use

```
disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.yellow, // Default border color
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.red, // Default border color
  ),
),
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    width: 1,
    color: Colors.blue, // 테두리를 투명하게 만듭니다.
  ),
),
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    width: 1,
    color: Colors.green, // Border color when focused
  ),
),
```

The radius of the border **must** be provided and also the width in focusedBorder as well as enabledBorder.